# Serialize classes based on Generics. Is it different?

Tags: unity

I have a certain `ScriptableObject`.

```
public class Biome : ScriptableObject { ... }
```

If I write the following in a component:

```
public List<Biome> list1;
```

This is what appears in the inspector:

[image]

So far so good. But if I try to make my list more generic, like this:

```
public class DistributedList<T>
{
    public List<T> items;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BiomeList : DistributedList<Biome> { }
```

This is what I get on the inspector:

[image]

All I can seem to be able to add now is just a name, not the Object itself.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity can't serialize classes that have generic fields. So while it can serialize your list of biomes, it cannot serialize a class containing a `List<T>`.

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/24/serialization-in-unity/

One of the solutions here may help you: https://answers.unity.com/questions/460727/how-to-serialize-dictionary-with-unity-serializati.html

Comment: To extend the answer, for the simplified intents and purposes of OP's question, a serializer basically treats `List<T>` the same as `List<object>`. You can put a `Biome` in a `List<object>`, but taking an item from a `List<object>` doesn't in any way signal that you're going to get a `Biome` object. This issue isn't just related to Unity, it's a sort of "common sense" in regards to C# polymorphism and the inability to automatically cast from a base class to a derived class.